# Movement algorithms for Java 2D Video Games

Tags: game-physics

I am working on a Java 2D Video game, and having issues with game movement when occurs on a diagonal.  If the game piece moves on a diagonal, it moves faster, as for the given unit of time, it is traversing more pixels. Also, issues given scaling of the X-axis and Y-axis having unequal pixel counts.

How to normalize game piece movements?  Also, would like to avoid use of a Game Engine to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

> Anybody know of a tutorial that covers how to normalize game piece movements where will not need a Phd in Math or Physics undertand this?

Well, solution is to use a [Unit Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector), which I believe was in high school curriculum, here in my country.

Basically, if you have the `x` and `y` components of speed, all you have to do is divide both with `Math.hypot(x, y)`.

Depending on the context, or game, you may wish to multiply both components (`x` and `y`) by some factor after the division, to speed things up.